# Android Programming Issue

Tags: java

I have an `Integer` variable and `int` array as follows:

```
Integer num= 10;

int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 10 };
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (num == i){
        print (num equal i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what wrong in the code?

Comment: please see my answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably needs this if condition:

```
 if(num==array[i]){//you need to compare to array element rather than index
    System.out.println (num  + " equals at index " + i);//you need a string to print.
 }
```